# How to count all rows in a joined table with a specific ID

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have two tables,  one is a list of songs.  The other is a list of projects.

They are joined by the songsID.  My query currently looks like this:-

```
$sQuery = "
        SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns))."
        FROM   $sTable
        LEFT JOIN
            $sTable2
            ON ($sTable2.songs_id = $sTable.songsID)
        $sWhere
        $sOrder
        $sLimit
    ";
    $rResult = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or die(mysql_error());
```

The $sTable and $sTable2 variables are the two tables clearly.

This works fine and lists all the rows I have in '$sTable'.  The JOIN that you see above is not necassary to list the songs but is as far as I am able to get with my limited MySQL ability.

What I would like to do is have another column returned in my JSON data that displays the total COUNT of all projects (in $sTable2) for EACH song in '$sTable'.  Therefore counting each project which has a specific 'songsID'.

$aColumns is the following:-

```
$aColumns = array( 'song_name', 'artist_band_name', 'author', 'song_artwork', 'song_file', 'genre', 'song_description', 'uploaded_time', 'emotion', 'tempo', 'songsID', 'user', 'happiness', 'instruments', 'similar_artists', 'play_count' );
```

These are the columns in $sTable, with 'songsID' being the auto increment primary key which is also stored in '$sTable2' to link the songs to their projects.

I need to be able to add 'projects_count' into the $aColumns array above.

Hopefully I have explained myself better this time.  Apologies that my SQL experience is absolutely minimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select count(*) as projects_count, a.songs_id
from Table2 a
group by a.songs_id
```

This will give you the number of projects per `songs_id`.

You can also query for specific song_id with:

```
select count(*) as projects_count
from Table2 where Table2.songs_id = <your_song_id>
```

And this:

```
select b.*, bb.projects_count from Table b 
left join (
   select count(*) as projects_count, a.songs_id
   from Table2 a
   group by a.songs_id
) bb on bb.songs_id = b.songsID
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect however I am terribly new to MySQL and am unsure how to implement this within my JOIN so that I have one query that will return all the songs in $sTable with the added column 'projects_count' containing the total number of projects (from $sTable2) for each song.  I am finding it quite difficult to articulate this problem, but a huge thanks for the help so far :-)

Comment: @gordyr I added an extra query that will bring all the columns of table 1 (song columns) with all the projects_count.

Comment: Fantastic, thats finally done it.  Sometimes when your learning something new even the simplest things can sometimes have you stumped for hours.  Conrads answer was pretty much there it just wasn't 100% in my case.  But huge thanks to you all. :-)